# (Elixir/Erlang) :ets.select_count returns 0

Tags: erlang, elixir, ets

I'm writing a program using Elixir and I have a very strange error.

I have a table, which contains some values stored like that: `{a, b}`. A is unique value, b can be repeated.

I want to count how many rows I have, which have specific second value.

When I call

```
:ets.select_count(table, [{{:'$1', "a"}, [], [:'$1']}])
```

it returns 0, but if I call

```
length(:ets.select(table, [{{:'$1', "a"}, [], [:'$1']}]))
```

it returns expected result.

Table can't be changed between these two calls.

Versions:

- erlang - 25.3.2.5
- elixir - 1.15.4
  (I took versions from package manager, tell me if it's wrong way)

I tried to find answer in google, I found nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

To reproduce:

```
table = :ets.new(:tbl, [])
:ets.insert(table, {"a", "b"})
:ets.insert(table, {"b", "a"})
IO.puts('select_count: #{:ets.select_count(table, [{{:'$1', "a"}, [], [:'$1']}])}') # prints 0
IO.puts('length(select): #{length(:ets.select(table, [{{:'$1', "a"}, [], [:'$1']}]))}') # prints 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Erlang docs:

https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets#select_count-2

> This function can be described as a select_delete/2 function that does not delete any elements, but only counts them.

So look at the docs for `select_delete/2`:

https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets#select_delete-2

> The match specification has to return the atom true if the object is to be deleted. No other return value gets the object deleted.

So you need to do this:

```
:ets.select_count(table, [{{:'$1', "a"}, [], [true]}])
```

Note the return value is `true`, to accord with the quote above.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have tried to read documentation, but apparently I read it inaccurately and missed this part. Thanks again